# Python Debugger out of sync with code

Tags: odoo, pdb

I am in the process of debugging something in OpenERP using Python 2.7.3.  The debugger seems to get out of sync with the code when stepping through with the Next (n) command.  See Code and output below.  I have the same problem with Python 2.6.5.  I have never experienced this before using Python pdb.

I believe the problem may be related to the way OpenERP calls my method through a Python exec() statement by reading the code field in the OpenERP XML below.  Is possible that calling Python code constructed dynamically and called via exec() is confusing the pdb debugger?

If this is the case is there a work around?

CODE called via this OpenERP action below:

```
<record id="action_wash_st_method1" model="ir.actions.server">
            <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
            <field name="condition">True</field>
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_view_tree_display_address_list"/>
            <field eval="5" name="sequence"/>
            <field name="code">
action = self.view_calc_sales_tax(cr, uid, context)
</field>
           <field name="name">wash state action request</field>
</record>

 <record model="ir.values" id="action_wash_st_tax_trigger_method1" >
            <field name="key2" eval="'tree_but_open'" />
            <field name="model" eval="'view.tree.display.address.list'" />
            <field name="name">Method1 Wash State</field>
            <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,%d'%action_wash_st_method1"/>
            <field name="object" eval="True" />
 </record>
```